# building a large xts object out of a list of files with rbind.xts and a user defined function

Tags: regex, r, xts, lapply, rbind

I am trying to create one large xts data set out of a list of files. I was able to accomplish this by being explicit as shown below, where `read.cqg` is a user defined function that using `read.zoo` and `as.xts` to read/convert the data into a xts object. So each `read.cqg` call returns a xts object.

The code below works and returns a large xts object.

```
large_xts_object <- rbind.xts(read.cqg("somefile01.txt"),
                              read.cqg("somefile02.txt"),
                              read.cqg("somefile03.txt"),
                              read.cqg("somefile04.txt"),
                              read.cqg("somefile05.txt"),
                              read.cqg("somefile06.txt"),
                              read.cqg("somefile07.txt"))
```

I would like to use regular expressions and `lapply` to avoid having to explicitly write the file name. This would help me understand using `lapply` and shorten the code.

This is my attempt, which doesn't give me the results I want.

```
large_xts_obj <- rbind.xts(lapply(list.files(pattern="^somefile*.*txt"), read.cqg))
```

This returns a large list of xts objects instead of just one large xts object. How can I use `rbind.xts`, my custom `read.cqg` function, and the `pattern` argument of `list.files` to create the single xts object I want?

Comment: `files = list.files(pattern = "^files*.*txt"),                                        large_xts_object <- do.call("rbind.xts", lapply(files,FUN = read.cqg))`                 It seems like this worked.. defined files from list.files() .. used do.call  idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call methods (e.g. `rbind.xts`) directly. Just use the generic function and let R do the method dispatch. Aside from that, the code in your comment is correct.

`do.call` allows you to construct and evaluate a function call by providing a function and a list of parameters. In this case, the list of parameters is your list of xts objects read via `read.cqg`.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "^files*.*txt")
xts_object_list <- lapply(files, read.cqg)
large_xts_object <- do.call(rbind, xts_object_list)
```